# Django: ModelChoiceField and django.setup()

Tags: python, django, django-settings

If I try to run a test via PyCharm, I get this exception

```
...bin/python /usr/local/pycharm-4.5.1/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py ...src/foo/foo/tests/FooEditTest.py::FooEditTest::test_issue_add true
Testing started at 15:59 ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/pycharm-4.5.1/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 139, in <module>
    module = loadSource(a[0])
  File "/usr/local/pycharm-4.5.1/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 41, in loadSource
    module = imp.load_source(moduleName, fileName)
  File "...src/foo/foo/tests/FooEditTest.py", line 45, in <module>
    from foo.views.issue.forward import forward
  File "...src/foo/foo/views/issue/forward.py", line 29, in <module>
    class ForwardForm(forms.Form):
  File "...src/foo/foo/views/issue/forward.py", line 36, in ForwardForm
    group=forms.ModelChoiceField(Group.objects.exclude(groupconfig__no_issue=True).extra(
  File "...python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 92, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "...python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 698, in exclude
    return self._filter_or_exclude(True, *args, **kwargs)
  File "...python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 707, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(~Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "...python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1331, in add_q
    clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases)
  File "...python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1358, in _add_q
    current_negated=current_negated, connector=connector)
  File "...python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1182, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_aggregate = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "...python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1120, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "...python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1383, in names_to_path
    field, model, direct, m2m = opts.get_field_by_name(name)
  File "...python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 416, in get_field_by_name
    cache = self.init_name_map()
  File "...python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 445, in init_name_map
    for f, model in self.get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model():
  File "...python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 563, in get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model
    cache = self._fill_related_many_to_many_cache()
  File "...python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 577, in _fill_related_many_to_many_cache
    for klass in self.apps.get_models():
  File "...python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 101, in wrapper
    result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
  File "...python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 168, in get_models
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "...python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I use `group=forms.ModelChoiceField(Group.objects.exclude(...))`
This line gets executed during importing. The call to `django.setup()` was not done before.

I have no clue how to solve this:

- Should I call `django.setup()`? But where to insert this line?
- Avoid using `MyModel.objects.filter(...)` during import time? This would need a big refactoring, since we have several `ModelChoiceField`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently running the tests using the PyCharm's Python unit test runner `pycharm-4.5.1/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py`.
This test runner is great for low-level unit tests (subclassed from `unittest.TestCase`) that don't touch Django features like the ORM, but 
if the tests rely on Django-specific things like the database, then your TestCases probably need to be subclassed from `django.test.testcases.TestCase` and you'll need to go through PyCharm's Django test manager `django_test_manage.py`, which takes care of setting up the test database, initialising the model registry, and so on.

Run > Edit Configurations > Add New Configuration (+ button) > Django Tests

Set the target to `foo.foo.tests.FooEditTest` and make sure to put `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=...` in the environment variables if it doesn't find your settings.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem while running test cases and solved it by adding this to test file at the beginning with import statements

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'
application = WSGIHandler()
```

Comment: I have about 500 test files. I would like to have a solution which is avoids copy+paste.

Comment: you can try adding these statements to the environment in IDE when running test cases. for instance I use pycharm and I add them to the environment variables

Comment: What should I add to the environment variables? DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'myapp.settings'? I guess this is already there. Otherwise I guess I would get different errors.

Answer (score 1):

Please show your exact code (especially the `extra()` clause). Calling `filter()` or `exclude()` at import time is not bad because querysets are lazy but you could evaluate the queryset here that caused the exception.

Do not evaluate querysets during import time because import statements are executed only once: e.g., if a new group is created, it won't be available as a choice for you ModelChoiceField.

Comment: Yes, this is a good hint. But how to avoid MyModel.objects.filter() in a ModelChoiceField, if you want to do filtering? Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield I don't want to write a Manager or ProxyModel each time I want to filter the queryset.

Comment: Are you sure that "Calling filter() or exclude() at import time is not bad because querysets are lazy" is true for Django>=1.7?

Comment: @guettli: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy

Answer (score 0):

A bit hard to say without seeing your code, but I had a similar issue once. For me it was related to a module that was being imported by my models and that also contained an import of my models.

**ModelA** --- *imports* --> **service** -- *imports* --> **ModelA**

I solved this by moving the import in my service to the method that needed the import. So instead of putting it at the top of the service module, I limited the scope of the import to the method that needed this import, thus avoiding importing the models whilst initializing the service module. Fwew, I wish I could draw it for you :)

Comment: I don't think it is a circular in my case. The code worked fine on Django1.6. We update the Django version at the moment. The import graph has not changed.